# Moment.diff is not a function

Tags: typescript, momentjs

I am trying to get the no of days between two dates using momentJs.

However, when I call the .diff function it gives an error:

> date1.diff is not a function

Below is my code:

```
import moment, { Moment } from "moment";

export class DateProvider {

    public static dateDifferenceInDays(date1: Moment, date2: Moment) {
        return date1.diff(date2, "days");
    }
}
```

And I call it like:

```
DateProvider.dateDifferenceInDays(date1, date2);
```